# html in a php variable

Tags: php, variables

I want to put some procedural stuff like html in a variable;

Normally we do this:

```
<?php

$my_var = '

    <h1>some header</h1>

    some text.

';

?>
```

Now I want it to look like this:

```
<?php

$my_var = '

?>

    <h1>some header</h1>

    some text.

<?php

';

?>
```

So that we open a php code, declare a variable, do some stuff outside php, and then reopen php code and close the var and we get that stuff that is outside php, we get it inside that variable.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
    <h1>some header</h1>
    some text.
<?php

$my_var = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo my_var;
?>
```

Comment: You might also use `$my_var = ob_get_clean();` instead of using `ob_get_contents();` and `ob_end_clean();`. [[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)]

Comment: @HashemQolami `ob_get_clean()` is my preferred way too but I thought I would show the beginner method.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is a way because php ignores lines outside the php tags.
if u have the php in a other file user [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: ups i fogott to think about ob_start

Answer (score 1):

Please check php heredoc

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Hope it helps